# Salesforce API - Using Compound fields. (Cannot deserialize instance of MailingAddress from VALUE_STRING)

Tags: rest, api, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Using REST API for Salesforce, I am trying to insert/update a contact into my business org where 'MailingAddress' is one of the fields with some set data, though in response I am getting this error message 'Cannot deserialize instance of MailingAddress from VALUE_STRING', the same response also resulting in 'OtherAddress'.

To my understanding, I think this is due to the reason that 'MailingAddress' and 'OtherAddress' are not actual fields that contains some String data, rather they take a dynamic address which resulting in filling up all other related fields like - 'MailingCity, MailingStreet, etc'.

So I have 2 questions:

**1.** How can I set 'MailingAddress' and 'OtherAddress' fields using API parameter only?

**2.** Is there any manual/documentation for this reference? As I am also having trouble with 'OtherLatitude' and 'OtherLogitude' fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Address and geolocation fields are compound fields.

You need to provide the value for the different components of the field, so for example, for MailingAddress you would need to provide MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingState or MailingStateCode, etc. And for OtherAddress you would provide OtherStreet, OtherCity, etc.

For more information on compound fields: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/compound_fields.htm

Comment: so does that mean we can not use compound fields in API parameter directly, and rather should use all its components?

Comment: Correct, compound fields are read-only, so you can use them in a query for example, but not for create or update. In that case you need to specify each component of the field (Street, City, etc.)